# Clear filters in ajax with DataTable

Tags: javascript, ajax

I can't clear the filters with the code below.

I'm using DataTable and Ajax.

The search is working correctly, however all filters are not working. When clicking the clear button, only the form is being cleared.

```
<form id="filter">
   <select name="product" class="product" multiple>
      <option value="1">Product 1</option>
      <option value="2">Product 2</option>
      <option value="3">Product 3</option>
      <option value="4">Product 4</option>
      <option value="5">Product 5</option>
      <option value="6">Product 6</option>
      <option value="7">Product 7</option>
      <option value="8">Product 8</option>
   </select>
   <button type="reset" id="clear" class="button secondary">Clear All</button>
</form>
<table id="table">
   <thead>
      <th>Product</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Product</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {           
       var table = $('#table').DataTable({
     
           ajax: {
               url: 'search.php',
               data: function(data) {
                   var product = $('.product').val();              
                   data.busca_product = product;
               }
           },
           dom: 'Plfrtip',     
           processing: true,
           serverSide: true,
           serverMethod: 'post',
           dataType: "json",
           columns: [
               {data: 'product_id'},
               {data: 'product_name'},
               {data: 'status'}
           ],
           deferRender: true,
            $('#clear').table().search('').draw();
       });
       $('.product').change(function() {
           table.draw();
       });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/2.2.0/js/dataTables.searchPanes.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="filter">
   <select name="product" class="product" multiple>
      <option value="1">Product 1</option>
      <option value="2">Product 2</option>
      <option value="3">Product 3</option>
      <option value="4">Product 4</option>
      <option value="5">Product 5</option>
      <option value="6">Product 6</option>
      <option value="7">Product 7</option>
      <option value="8">Product 8</option>
   </select>
   <button type="reset" id="clear" class="button secondary">Clear All</button>
</form>
<table id="table">
   <thead>
      <th>Product</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Product</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What code? You haven't provided anything.

Comment: Sorry, the tool that limits code insertion. But I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

`$('#clear').table().search('').draw()` here the `$('#clear')` selector selects the button, it has no connection with the datatable. You could separately try `table.ajax.reload()` on onclick of the reset/clear button.

```js
$('#clear').onclick(function() {
     table.ajax.reload();
});
```

reference docs: [datatable docs for table reload](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

**Note:** when you click the `Clear All` button, it resets the form because of html reset value of the type property. `$('#clear').table().search('').draw()` does not celar the form.